# Errors capturing screenshot with headless selenium and chromedriver

Tags: selenium, screenshot

We have a headless selenium running as part of a maven build script using chromedriver as a RemoteWebDriver and running using xvfb. Our tests on the environment and querying the underlying html dom execute fine. The problem we're facing is once we try taking screenshots of the test results

When running locally it runs fine and takes screenshots properly using the getScreenShotAs Java function, however when we run it on our CI server (ubuntu), we receive the error

"Internal Chrome error during 'CaptureEntirePage': (Taking a page snapshot is not supported on this platform)."

We're running the same version of all tools both on my local system and on the server.

Has anyone experienced this issue before and any ideas on how to work around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed with Chrome 17 (currently beta, available on the [dev channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)).

Answer (score 2):

What version of Chrome are you using?

It looks like you cannot take screenshots right now in Chrome 14 on Linux:
http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium/chromium.git;a=commit;h=f2c7147b14a7ab404bfe2195702409a0d06196d5

Screenshots work in Chrome 13. It's not easy to downgrade but this process worked for me:
http://japhr.blogspot.com/2011/07/downgrading-google-chrome-unstable-on.html

Answer (score 0):

After extensive searching, I found some older versions of Chromium here:
https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/stable/+packages

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, either improve it or remove it